# $2xy+\ln y=x \sin x$. Find $y'$.

Tags: derivatives

> Let $2xy+\ln y=x \sin x$. Find $y'$.

**My work:**
$$2xy+\ln y=x \sin x$$
$$2y+2xy'+\frac{y'}{y}=\sin x+x\cos x$$

*What next?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Factorize:**

$$y'(2x+\frac{1}{y})=\sin x+x\cos x-2y$$
which implies:
$$y'=\frac{\sin x+x\cos x-2y}{(2x+\frac{1}{y})}$$
which is your answer.

Comment: Ok. It is finish?

Comment: @Roman83 unless you know what the product log function(Lambert W function) is then this is the end

Answer (score 2):

if you want to find the answer using Lambert W then this is the way:

$$x \sin (x)=2xy+\ln (y)\\e^{x \sin (x)}=e^{2xy}y=y(e^{2x})^y$$

now set $e^{x \sin (x)}=z,e^{2x}=a$ and we get: $z=ya^y$, this is a very know form and the answer for this is the following:
$$y = \frac{W\left(\ln (a)z\right)}{\ln(a)}\text{ where $W(x)$ is the Lambert W function.}$$
putting the value of $z$ and $a$ we obtain: $$y = \frac{W\left(2x \,e^{x \sin(x)}\right) }{2 x}$$

---

the derivative of $W(x)$ is $\LARGE{\frac {W(x)}{x+xW(x)}}$

---

now let's take the derivative of $y$:

$$y'=\frac{2x\left[W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)\right]'-2W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}{4x^2}\\=\frac{2xW'\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)\left(2e^{x\sin(x)}
\left(x^2\cos(x)+x\sin(x)+1\right)\right)-2W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}{4x^2}\\=\frac{x\frac{W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}{2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}+2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}\left(2e^{x\sin(x)}
\left(x^2\cos(x)+x\sin(x)+1\right)\right)-W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}{2x^2}\\
\boxed{=\frac{\frac{2W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}{1+W\left(x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}
\left(x^2\cos(x)+x\sin(x)+1\right)-W\left(2x\,e^{x\sin(x)}\right)}{2x^2}}$$

---

if you don't know/didn't study the Lambert W function then you probably don't need to solve it with this way

Answer (score 1):

solving for $$y'$$ we get
$$y'(2x+\frac{1}{y})=\sin(x)+x\cos(x)-2y$$
it must be $$2x+\frac{1}{y}\ne 0$$!

Answer (score 1):

By differentials:

$$2xy+\ln y=x \sin x\implies2ydx+2xdy+\frac{dy}{y}=\sin x dx+x\cos xdx\\\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sin x+x\cos x-2y}{(2x+\frac{1}{y})}
$$